# Getting Random.h (uses unistd.h) to work on VC++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to C++. I want to use the header file Random.h (described here http://ftp.arl.mil/random/). It uses unistd.h
Which gives me an error

"Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory"

I've googled around and seen that the issue is that unistd.h works with unix not visual express. Some posts suggest using mingw instead but I've tried that and it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to get unistd.h (or at least the bits of it I need) to work on Visual Express. 
There are some suggestions online but I cant find anything that addresses my particular question.
thanks!

Comment: That's an old library. C++ today has a standard library containing `<random>` (note: no .h). It was added to VC++ back in 2008.

Comment: but random doesn't let you define your own distributions (Random.h does)

Comment: PS I had already found the "answer" you point out. But this did not address my particular problem (this is exactly what I was referring to in the last line of my original post)

Comment: @user3111174 yes it does

Comment: jalf- you are too quick to assume what is and isn't helpful. I studied that previous answer in great detail and implemented it. Didnt work for me. The detailed answer below (which was SPECIFIC to my question) did solve my problem. The previous answer was not clear enough for someone new to C++. You may think they are the same but for me it was the difference between my code working and it not...

Answer (score 0):

It is including unistd.h for calls to getpid().  Change the #include to <process.h> and change all the getpid() calls to _getpid() (note the extra underscore at the front).

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2y34y40.aspx

Comment: thanks Alan. By "Change the #include to" do you mean delete the line #include <unistd.h> or were you saying I should change it to another header file (I think the end of your sentence might be missing)

Comment: thanks Alan. By "Change the #include to" do you mean delete the line #include <unistd.h> or were you saying I should change it to another header file (I think the end of your sentence might be missing)

Comment: I have fixed the answer.  The angle brackets were being treated as HTML

Comment: I've tried #include <process.h> and replacing getpid() with _getpid() but I still get loads of errors: error C2864: 'Random::_F' : a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type  error C2065: 'M_PI' : undeclared identifier etc

Comment: Did you put #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES before #include <math.h>?  Have another look at that link.

Comment: great that helps. Still have the other error though: error C2864 : 'Random::_F' : a static data member with an in - class initializer must have non - volatile const integral type

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++ will not let you assign static const doubles in the header file (ony integer types).  You will need to change the line in the .h file to this...

```
static const double _F;
```

Then create a Random.cpp file that just contains this...

```
#include "Random.h"

// Initialize static variable
const double Random::_F    = 1. / Random::_M;
```